# Mumbai Network Tokens are not being listed as "created by `you`" in testnet.opensea.io

Tags: testnets, polygon, opensea

Here is an example tokens description part of a contract in Mumbai network.

[image]

And below you see the description part of that exact same contract in Rinkeby network.

[image]

Due to this issue I can not delete the collection that I created.

[image]

I even sent a support ticket to opensea.io about this problem, they simply said that "they are fixing bugs." which literally doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Same issue here.... any luck resolving this?

Comment: Nobody seem to care about this, sadly no solution yet. @rbinnun